# Argument passed by value or const reference in the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-value, pass-by-const-reference

Which constructor is better for the following class?

```
struct Foo
{ 
  Foo(const int& val):val_(val){} // constructor 1    
  Foo(int val):val_(val){} // constructor 2
  int val_;
};
```

Without any compiler optimization, do they copy val only once or does constructor 2 create a further copy before the initialization list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first constructor is called, the argument passed to it will **not** be copied. The `val` argument will bind to the argument passed (**copy by reference**).

If the second constructor is called, the argument passed to it will be **copied by value**.

Both constructors are the same in that they initialize `_val` with `val` respectively and perform an additional **copy by value**.

So, without any optimizations, it looks like this:

```
                                                    Copies
const int& constructor          1
int constructor                          2
```

Comment: This is technically true. However, the reference will probably be compiled to a pointer, which means that the *pointer* has to be copied instead of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, constructor 2 will make a copy twice: first time on call and the second time on intialization.
On the other hand, you understand that reference is nothing more than a pointer and as the size of referenced variable decreases to pointer size there is no cost reduction between contsructors 1 and 2.

Comment: Although one of the copies can be elided.

Comment: Yes that was my guess. So second do an additional copy without optimization. So for big object is better the first solution. Or maybe, even better, is to pass a int&& directly.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you never need to pass `int` variables by const reference.

The real question is: Why do you care? There will only be a measurable speed difference if `Foo` is constructed inside a loop with very many iterations **and** it is pretty much the only thing which happens inside that loop - very unlikely.

So just use #2. Not because of efficiency but because it is simpler.

Comment: int was only for seek of simplicity. Use a templated argument instead of int. My question was about the number of copy if no copy-elision is performed by the compiler